# Showing That Two Normal-Based Random Variables Have the Same Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

[image: Exercise 1.5]

Above is my question. $\overline X$ has distribution $N(0,1/n)$ - that's fine to work out. Similarly, $X_n / \sqrt{n}$ has distribution $N(0,1/n)$. These follow from the general relation
$$ \sum_{m=1}^n a_m X_m  ~\tilde ~~ N(\sum_m a_m \mu_m , \sum_m (a_m \sigma_m)^2)$$
(see Wikipedia for a derivation). However, I am stuck on determining the distribution of $\sum_{m=1}^n (X_m - \overline X)^2$ - or, rather, determining it in terms of $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} X_m^2$.

Any help would be most appreciated.

Thanks, Sam.

Comment: Two hints 1) The second term of each pair follows a Chi square distribution witn $n-1$ degree of freedom 2) it seems to me that even if you demostrante that, that would be not enough, because you need to show that the joint distribution is the same (not merely each of them, i.e., the marginals)

Comment: Yes, good point. So as mentioned below in the answer, if I show tha they're independent, then I only need to know the distributions of each individual ones, whereas in general I need to know the *joint* distribution (which isn't just the product in the general case). This is correct, yeah?

Comment: That's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of observations:

(i) As functions of independent random variables, $\dfrac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}\,\,$ is independent of $\,\,\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}{X_m^2}\,$.

(ii) $\,\,\dfrac{X_n}{\sqrt{n}}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, 1/n\right)\,\,$ and $\,\,\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}{X_m^2}\sim\chi^2(n-1)\,$, since they are linear combinations of independent, standard normal and squared standard normal random variables, respectively.



By [Cochran's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem),

(iii) $\,\,\bar{X}$ and $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\left(X_m-\bar{X}\right)^2$ are independent;

(iv)$\,\,\,\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\left(X_m-\bar{X}\right)^2\sim\chi^2\left(n-1\right)$;


Finally,

(v) $\,\,\bar{X}\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0, 1/n\right)\,\,$, since it is a linear combination of independent standard normal random variables.

Together, (i) to (v) imply the result.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I haven't actually heard of Cochran's Theorem - I'll look that up when I come back from lectures. I've heard of the $\chi^2$ distribution, but I had actually forgotten about it! How would I derive the $\chi^2$ part of (ii) and part (iiii)?

Comment: @SmileySam, $\,\,\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n-1}{X_m^2}\sim\chi^2(n-1)\,$ follows, by definition, because it is a sum of $n-1$ independent, squared normal random variables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution#Definition.  And, $\,\,\,\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=1}^{n}\left(X_m-\bar{X}\right)^2\sim\chi^2\left(n-1\right)$ follows from Cochran's theorem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how to apply Cochran's theorem to obtain (iii)/(iiii). Are you able to shed a bit more light on this, for me? Thanks!

Comment: @SmileySam, The only detailed example, under the section "examples" on the Wikipedia page for Cochran's theorem, is precisely the application of the theorem that you need: it shows exactly how the the theorem implies both (iii) and (iv). There, a sum of squared normal random variables is rewritten as the sum of two independent, chi-square random variables (as guaranteed by the theorem); one of which is a function of the sample mean and the other the sample variance. There really isn't more to it than that. I encourage you to read this well-known example.

Comment: Ah, hadn't noticed that. Thank you! I shall read through it tomorrow. 11pm is a bit late for maths! =P Thanks very much! :)

Comment: @SmileySam, Glad to have been of some help.